# Rerun jQuery each after AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the code

```
var expired_overlay=$('.expired-overlay');

expired_overlay.each(function(){
var t=$(this),
    p=$(this).closest('.coupon'),
    ph=p.height()+ ((p.css('padding-top').replace("px", ""))*2);
t.css({'width':p.width(),'height':ph,'opacity':0.5})

});
```

This runs on firstload on the desired items. But the script may need to load new items with AJAX. What is the best way to run this code again after new items have been loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to run the .each loop again after ajax contents are loaded.
So make this as function and call again when ajax call is finished :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ajaxComplete handler.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/.  It triggers when all AJAX calls are complete.

```
$('.log').ajaxComplete(function() {
  SpecialFunction();
});

SpecialFunction() {
  var expired_overlay=$('.expired-overlay');

  expired_overlay.each(function(){
  var t=$(this),
    p=$(this).closest('.coupon'),
    ph=p.height()+ ((p.css('padding-top').replace("px", ""))*2);
  t.css({'width':p.width(),'height':ph,'opacity':0.5})

  });
}
```